# KubernetesManifest@0 error- Input required: kind

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I m trying to run below ADO task but getting error:
Writing this to facilitate automatic tasks to few people in team.

```
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.BringDown, 'true')}}:
      - task: KubernetesManifest@0
        displayName: Scale down
        inputs:
          action: scale
          arguments: deployment mydeployment-name  --replicas=0 
          namespace: ${{ parameters.Environment }}
```

Error:

## ##[warning]Resource file has already set to: /home/vsts/work/_tasks/KubernetesManifest_dee316a2-586f-4def-be79-488a1f503dfe/0.181.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tasks-kubernetes-common-v2/module.json

```
        Kubectl Client Version: v1.19.0
        Kubectl Server Version: v1.17.9
```

==============================================================================
##[error]Input required: kind

The other task I tried worked well:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.Restart, 'true')}}:
              - task: KubernetesManifest@0
                displayName: Delete POD
                inputs:
                  action: delete
                  arguments: pod -l app="${{ parameters.service }}"
                  namespace: ${{ parameters.Environment }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the action to scale for this task, please note that there are other required parameters for the [Kubernetes manifest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops), as below.

[image]

See: [Scale action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops#scale-action) for details.